# C++ bicubic interpolation with a thermal image

Tags: c++, math, interpolation, bicubic

At the moment I'm using a MLX90641 sensor on a STM32 to get a temperature grid.
The grid itself is 18x12 pixels.
I'd like to bicubic interpolate this grid to a 31x23 one, I think that's the most logical one?

My math / calculus knowledge is just sufficient enough to grasp the idea of bicubic interpolation. Yet I can't figure out to make it work in code.

Used language is C++ and https://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic as a source.

```
double cubicInterpolate (double p[4], double x) {
    return p[1] + 0.5 * x*(p[2] - p[0] + x*(2.0*p[0] - 5.0*p[1] + 4.0*p[2] - p[3] + x*(3.0*(p[1] - p[2]) + p[3] - p[0])));
}

double bicubicInterpolate (double p[4][4], double x, double y) {
    double arr[4];
    arr[0] = cubicInterpolate(p[0], y);
    arr[1] = cubicInterpolate(p[1], y);
    arr[2] = cubicInterpolate(p[2], y);
    arr[3] = cubicInterpolate(p[3], y);
    return cubicInterpolate(arr, x);
}
```

Do I loop through my array of doubles and call the function bicubicInterpolate on each value?
Why do they use parameters double x, double y?

Anyone able to help me apply this function to my double grid[192]?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems you are missing the part of the code that actually show you how to apply this back to a matrix larger than 4x4 (or 5x5).  From the article "Bicubic interpolation can be used to resize images. However, this is (currently) out of the scope of this article. Please don't ask me questions about that." Seems the author is either a bit fuzzy on this or wants to get paid for the work...

Comment: I don’t think your source is good. When I need stuff like that, I use gtengine. Here’s their implementation of bicubic interpolation: https://github.com/davideberly/GeometricTools/blob/GTE-version-5.7/GTE/Mathematics/IntpBicubic2.h#L141-L233 As a first step you can use the complete class, then as an optimization replace `mBlend` 4x4 matrix with a local `constexpr` one, the values are there: https://github.com/davideberly/GeometricTools/blob/GTE-version-5.7/GTE/Mathematics/IntpBicubic2.h#L71-L86

Comment: About the higher-level part, you loop through the output image, and call that `operator()` once for each output pixel.

Comment: https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-interpolation.htm - notice the nice picture part way down the page where they visualize how the various filters work - spread your known pixels out and use the filters to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Show us how your input and output grid is stored (I mean code of their declaration of the grids).  What data type , topology? what are the values ranges? Do you have sample input? You wrote `grid[192]?` implying you got data as linear 1D array however `18*12=216` ... and values are `double`? You use C++ on STM32? My experience is C++ is not usable on STM32 IDEs as it fights with the GUI configuration lib. However I do not use STM32 (I heavily use AVR32 as they much better) so I might just have something wrongly set but doubt it as even empty C++ code does not compile ...

Comment: btw I used STM32 only once for single project as my Employer insisted but they so much worse even he agreed to not use them for serious work.